# Large Set of Random Variables with Exponential Distribution

Tags: central-limit-theorem, exponential-distribution, poisson-distribution

I'm struggling to understand how to solve the following problem. I have a random variable $X$ that represents the life time of a cellphone (in years) and I know that such variable follows an exponential distribution with $\lambda = 0.22$, that is $$X \sim Exponential(0.22)$$

**Considering that I have a set of 500 cellphones, all following the same distribution, what is the approximate probability of no more than 80 cellphones die during the first year of utilization?**

I've calculated what is the probability of one cellphone to die during the first year of utilization and it is approximately 20%. But I wasn't sure what to do with this result.

I've also tried to employ the Central Limit Theorem, hinted by "approximate probability", and I've obtained a Normal Distribution for $\overline{X}$, the median of the data set, such that $$\overline{X} ~ Normal(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}})$$ with $$\mu = \frac{1}{\lambda} = 4.55$$ and $$\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}} = \frac{1}{\lambda^2 \sqrt{N}} = 0.92$$ However i'm still not sure on what to do here.

Is the problem related to the poisson probability?

Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is given by the Binomial distribution.  After all, the event "die during the first year" doesn't care about how the deaths happen to be distributed; all that matters its chance of occurring for each phone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're having trouble making sense of this problem because the answer is extreme.

"Failure" is that such a phone lasts less than a year.
From R, we get $P(F) = 0.1975,$ pretty much as you say. 
So $p = P(S) =  0.8025.$ (A falure rate - $\lambda = 0.22$ implies that cell phones last on average for
$1/\lambda = 4.5454$ years.

```
pexp(1, .22)
[1] 0.1974812
```

Now if you have $n = 500$ such phones working or failing independently, let $Y$ be the number that
survive for at least a year. Then $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=500, p),$ which has $\mu=E(Y) = 401.2594$ and $\sigma=SD(Y) = 8.9018.$

As I read the problem, you seek $P(Y > 80) = 1 -P(Y \le 80).$ If you wish, you can use the normal approximation to a binomial distribution (a special case of the CLT) to approximate this probability. But you could also use R (where 'pbinom' is a binomial CDF) to see that the exact probability is essentially $1:$

```
1 - pbinom(80, 500, 0.8025) 
[1] 1
```

[image]

This is no surprise because the mean (about 400) is
so many standard deviations above 80.

A normal approximation would be as follows:
$$P(Y > 80) = P\left(\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}
> \frac{80-401.2594}{8.9018} = -39.17\right)  \approx P(Z > =39.17) \approx 1,$$
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.

*Note:* What may be causing a surprise is that not many textbook problems have 'essentially 1' as an answer.
Perhaps 380 was intended instead of 80.

```
1 - pbinom(380, 500, 0.8025) 
[1] 0.9888621
```